# debugging shader that do not output to screen in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, directx

I am trying to debug DirectX shaders in Visual Studio. Shaders are stored in files with .fx extension and compiled at application runtime. If the output of rendering is directed to the screen, I am able to click the capture frame button, obtain fraphics pipeline and debug my shaders. However if the rendering output is directed to a buffer in memory, the capture frame button does not seem to work. Is there any possibility to debug shaders when the output is not directed to the screen?